# Can QGIS generate multiple lines by a line based on distance

Tags: qgis

Can QGIS generate multiple lines based on distance, and try to use the gadgets or plug-ins in it to generate lines

Comment: Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.